# sqlplus select record between merged dates

Tags: sqlplus

> table name :document_archive_doc_perms

table desc:

```
 - location char(1),  document_id  number(5),  permission_id number(5),
   permission_type char(1), date_time_from date,  date_time_to date,
   ecode number(5), ecode_s number(2),  approved_by number(5),
   approved_by_ecode number(2), approved_on date, primary
   key(location,document_id,permission_id));
```

my query :

```
select permission_id,document_id,date_time_from,date_time_to,approved_on,permission_type from document_archive_doc_perms 
where document_id=3 and ecode=1695 and approved_on is not null and (sysdate between date_time_from and date_time_to);
```

my output is

```
PERMISSION_ID DOCUMENT_ID DATE_TIME DATE_TIME APPROVED_ P
------------- ----------- --------- --------- --------- -
            5           3 01-DEC-14 31-DEC-14 08-DEC-14 V
            7           3 09-DEC-14 31-DEC-14 09-DEC-14 P
```

here my need is the latest permission from records(ie max of permission_id)
how to do this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an anaylitic `rank()` call:

```
SELECT permission_id, 
       document_id, 
       date_time_from, 
       date_time_to, 
       approved_on, 
       permission_type
FROM   (SELECT permission_id, 
               document_id, 
               date_time_from, 
               date_time_to, 
               approved_on, 
               permission_type,
               RANK() OVER (ORDER BY perission_id ASC) AS rk
        FROM   document_archive_doc_perms 
        WHERE  document_id = 3 AND 
               ecode = 1695 AND 
               approved_on IS NOT NULL AND 
               SYSDATE BETWEEN date_time_from AND date_time_to
       )
WHERE  rk = 1
```